# Wordpress Plugin - cURL is not installed on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, onesignal

I'm getting the following message in a Wordpress plugin - OneSignal.

`OneSignal Push: cURL is not installed on this server. cURL is required to send notifications. Please make sure cURL is installed on your server before continuing.`

I'm running WordPress 4.6.1 on LEMP stack - Ubuntu 14.04.5, Php5.5.9

As per few suggestions from Stackoverflow, I've installed php5-curl and have the curl.so file in the extension_dir. I've added the line `extension=curl.so` in php.ini file in /etc/php5/fpm

Still the error doesn't seem to go away. What needs to be done here?

Comment: Do you restart the server ?

Comment: Yes. I did restart the nginx server. But the error still shows up in wordpress.

Comment: you're supposed to restart php itself

Comment: I restarted php5. But the error still shows up in wordpress.

Comment: Check the web server config and see which PHP version it's using. Then find the folder belonging to this PHP version, containing the object files (.so) and see if curl.so is present.

Comment: Nginx is using php5-fpm. There is no curl.so under the /usr/lib/php5/* path. Currently it is under /usr/lib/php/* path. How do I get it here?

Comment: The `php-config --extension-dir` command will print path to the extension directory used. Check if this is the same directory where you were looking for `curl.so`.

Comment: I updated php5.5.9 to php5.6 along with other dependencies and then installed php5.6-curl. The issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to install php5.6-curl like this: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`

Comment: Note the php5.**6**-curl if you use php5-curl you might have installed it for the wrong version

Comment: I updated php5.5.9 to php5.6 along with other dependencies and then installed php5.6-curl. The issue is resolved now.

Comment: Can use php -v to find the PHP version first.